# Device Data to Dashboard: What architecture do I use (example inside)?

Tags: system-architecture

I want to filter my device data through a rule engine where I apply different actions to it before storing and displaying it to the user. I need to store this data into a time series database and I also need to display it in near real time. This is the data flow that I think is necessary. Anyone have an architectural example they can recommend? I am looking at ThingsBoard at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use TIG architecture. TIG stands for Telegraf, InfluxDB and Grafana. There are many tutorials avilable online on how to configure this architecture. You can follow this [medium article.](https://medium.com/@hoanglc/tig-stack-powerful-monitoring-tool-822521dce102)

The architecture of this looks as shown in the below image. You can have all your rules in the telegraf stack. You can also configure telegraf such a way that it can act as bridge between different protocols. In this example, I am using it as a bridge between MQTT broker and InfluxDB. You can through in a little python or shell script that can handle your rules.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the AWS ecosystem for this ? i.e, a combination of IoT Core, kinesis,  timeseries DB, etc ?

Here's an example:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/timestream/home?region=us-east-1#tutorials/6

More at
https://console.aws.amazon.com/timestream/home?region=us-east-1#tutorials

Comment: Yes and No, We don't want a cloud-based PaaS

Comment: You could self host something from Kafka for this. See https://lenses.io/blog/2016/12/kafka-influxdb/